# C#: Can I create inherit class without using a constructor of the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I need to make an **inherit class** with use of constructor, not defined in the **base** class? Problem is, that **constructor** in inherit class requires `:base()` constructor? How can this problem be solved without changing any component of the **base** class?

Comment: Can you use the standard constructor of the base clase like :BaseClass() ?

Comment: Please add some class declarations and constructor signatures as a minimum. At the moment your question is very unclear.

Comment: Since when was it required to call a base constructor using `: base()`?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example, its not clear to me what is being asked.

Comment: can you show us your code..that would help us give you proper solution..

Comment: @BoltClock Well, it's *always* required to call the base class's constructor from a child class, but if you don't do it explicitly it will implicitly call the parameter-less constructor.

Comment: @Servy: Bah, that was confusing on my part, I did mean to quote the question on requiring the use of `: base()` ;) I fixed my comment.

Answer (score 12):

No. Creating an instance of a derived class *always*<sup>1</sup> means chaining to the base class constructor, either explicitly or implicitly (and possibly indirectly, via other constructors in the derived class).

It doesn't have to be the parameterless constructor though. For example, you could have:

```
public class Base
{
    private readonly int id;

    public Base(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(int id) : base(id)
    {
    }
}
```

The values you use for the arguments to the base class constructor don't have to be directly related to the parameters though. For example, using the same base class as above, you could have:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Derived(string name) : base(name.Length)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Derived() : base(-1)
    {
        this.name = null;
    }
}
```

The important thing is that each class gets to ensure that it is constructed in a valid way. For example, `Base` might validate that the `id` is an even number, or something like that - it would be awful if you could bypass that validation when creating an instance of the derived class, as the rest of the code in `Base` then couldn't depend on it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Okay, may be weird cases where no constructors are invoked at all due to serialization or other such magic. Ignoring those though...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with having an inherited class that has constructors with different arguments than the base class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Parent()
    {
        Value = 5;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Child(string text)
        : base()  //note this line can be omitted; the compiler will add it automatically
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to implement a class without **constructor**. Even if you do not **define** any, the *default* constructor works as `public BaseClass() { }`. It must be because you can't *access* the constructor defined in base class. Now the problem is whether you don't want to change the base class implementation or you can not at all.

You will need to change the access modifier of base class constructor (which is probably private or internal) to **protected** or **public**.